# How to find CoreData Object via multiple relationships

Tags: swift, xcode, core-data, relation

I have a number of CoreData objects that are have multiple relationships. I'll focus on one, Answer. The CoreData relationships look like this:

[image]

It has no fields of its own, simply acts as a connector for three entities.

How do I construct a search where I get back any Answers that have all three related objects?

```
protocol MenuCoreDataDelegate {
    func addNewAnswer(team : Team?, challenge : DBChallenge?, video: DBVideo) -> Answer?
    func updateAnswer()
}
```

When creating a new Answer, I pass in three objects, and I'd do the same with the update function, but how is the query constructed?

Currently, I can just intersect the .answer related objects for each of the objects, which would be fine, but it seems like a more db oriented solution is out there?

Comment: Construct a NSPredicate for it. `NSPredicate(format: "%K = %@ AND %K = %@ AND %K = %@", argumentArray: [#keyPath(Answer.challenge), theTargetChallenge, #keyPath(Answer.team), theTargetTeam, #keyPath(Answer.videos): theTargetVideo]`? And if for instance, `team` has a particular `identifier` named `id`, you could do instead for that part `#keyPath(Answer.team.id), theTargetTeamId`

Comment: Yes that is exactly what I was going to suggest as well. Only question is if `videos` is a to-many relationship or if it's just has a confusing name.

Comment: videos is a to-many relationship. Does this affect the Predicate construction? I assume it then becomes an Array?